# React history.push sending page request?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am running into a very sporadic issue. It doesn't happen often but, in our React application, **history.push(URL)** does not always work as intended.

Typically, history.push will be handled by the React UI to navigate between React routes - it won't send an actual page request for whatever the URL is. 99% of the time this works perfectly fine - however, we are seeing cases in which **history.push(URL) is actually sending PAGE REQUESTS to the server.** This results in a **404 Not Found** error.

Here is the code snippet:

```
this.props.history.push(`/live?watchNow=true`)
```

In what scenario should this actually happen?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `history.push` isn't doing that if you are just pushing route paths your app can handle. Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates and reproduces this issue?

Comment: The server you've deployed your app to or are otherwise serving the app from needs to be configured to redirect page requests to the root `index.html` file so the React app loads and can handle routing/navigation internally. See the CRA [Deployment Docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) and search for the relevant server environment and follow the guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the UI to `/live` route. Since React is a SPA (in case you do not use Server Side Rendering), it won't make a request for a new page to the server. But if you refresh the page with `/live?watchNow=true`, you browser will make a request to ressource`/live?watchNow=true` with parameter `watchNow`, nevertheless it should show up.

By the way `push` from useHistory do not make HTTP request ([Docs](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/history)), so check elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So if the app happens to refresh for whatever reason - it requests resource. I suppose my next question should be why does the resource become unavailable?

Comment: That is really hard to response. You know with React, handle your state behaviour is sometime the most difficult thing to to do. Maybe check your state changing process: useEffect (most of the time causing the issue, setState, urls' API calls, caching updating function (may cause re-rendering). Good luck! 

Comment: It's nothing at all to do with React really. @AlexanderLe the resource "becomes unavailable" because it doesn't exist on the server where you are requesting it. See my [comment](/questions/73561698/react-history-push-sending-page-request#comment129908487_73561698) above about configuring the server.